# Python 3 finding a equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python 3 program we're it will find the vertex by completing the square.  ax2 + bx + c ---> a(x-h)2 + k the 2s are the small ones could anyone help me?

Comment: At least tag properly... /

Comment: You're having 2 different questions here: `1` how to complete the square (which is for [math.se], and even then, have many duplicates there), and `2` how to program it (show your effort, where are you stuck at?)

Comment: You should try something yourself, then ask for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. You have one equation of the form ax² + bx + c and you reshape it to the form a(x-h)² + k? And you want to solve this with python?

Comment: I can help with the math: a(x-h)²+k = ax²-2ahx+ah²+k yields h = -b/(2a), k = c - b²/(4*a)

Comment: try asking your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `replace`:

```
'ax2 + bx + c'.replace('x','(x-h)').replace('b(x-h) + c','k')
```